# Regular expression for first and last name

Tags: regex, validation

For website validation purposes, I need first name and last name validation.

For the first name, it should only contain letters, can be several words with spaces, and has a minimum of three characters, but a maximum at top 30 characters. An empty string shouldn't be validated (e.g. *Jason*, *jason*, *jason smith*, *jason smith*, *JASON*, *Jason smith*, *jason Smith*, and *jason SMITH*).

For the last name, it should be a single word, only letters, with at least three characters, but at most 30 characters. Empty strings shouldn't be validated (e.g. *lazslo*, *Lazslo*, and *LAZSLO*).

Comment: What about first names like 'Jo'?

Comment: just a remark: hyphens are common in lastnames ... maybe there are lastnames with spaces, too

Comment: This validation will be for a non english site thus in my country less or more smallest name is 3 letters :) Also it will be used for a facebook connect to my e commerce site entegration. Thus some stupid facebook names like "Danielle Cage ッ" or "Hopee Lamb-" shouldnt be validated, user will be asked to rewrite their names - sirnames in that case :)

Comment: Note: a regularexpressionvalidator will ignore empty inputs: this might or might not be what you want.

Comment: If at all possible, unless you have an amazingly compelling reason for requiring a first and last name, just provide a single "Name" field. http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: Khoisan names, amongst others, makes use of special characters like "!".  Irish surnames may make use of apostrophes.

Comment: Although I'm against any strict validation of names, in some scenarios it is vital to validate. For example for ID verification, the name user types into the form must match exactly to the names in the documents (e.g. drivers licence, passport, etc.). And you might be surprised how often people make typos or put special characters into the name fields. Make sure you provide a good error messaging as well.

Comment: According to ICAO which also defines standards for international passports, the max number of characters in the name must be 31.

Comment: **Why?** A user's first and last name consists of whatever they decide to use. This is a legal fact. You don't have any *requirement* to 'validate' it at all.

Comment: or what about "X Æ A-12" https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1257508900812713984

Comment: @AlexanderBurakevych I am having a hard time finding a document defining the passport standard. Could you link it here please ?

Comment: Having multi language support is essential, BUT would it be acceptable to limit any given word to only contain one alphabet to avoid mixing look alike characters to spoof other registered names?

Answer (score 299):

### Don't forget about names like:

- Mathias d'Arras
- Martin Luther King, Jr.
- Hector Sausage-Hausen

#### This should do the trick for most things:

`/^[a-z ,.'-]+$/i`

#### OR Support international names with super sweet unicode:

`/^[a-zA-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõøùúûüųūÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŲŪŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð ,.'-]+$/u`

Comment: I can't save this with č charactor my editor is showing exceptions . .  what wil do?

Comment: @coderex, utf8-encoded characters in your source code are not supported by all programming languages.

Comment: macek, you're missing quite a few characters to support even common Latin-using languages (Polish, for example). This further demonstrates that the whole effort is simply futile.

Comment: I would escape the [special characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Special_characters_in_regular_expressions) in these regexps - especially `.` (decimal point/dot/full stop) since it's the regexp wildcard =)

Comment: @murmux: it seems you are right! All theses years escaping dots for naught! I believe I developed the habit when coding in [classic JScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript) - not sure if it made a difference back then either =)

Comment: You cannot validate all the possible national characters. For example Hungarian characters `őŐűŰ` are missing, Polish characters `łŁ` as well, not to mention a number of Lithuanian and Latvian characters. Rather try to find a library which transforms the exotic characters into the proper accent-less version, then write the `/^[a-z ,.'-]+$/i` regexp.

Comment: So is `陳大文` not a valid name here?

Comment: For Unicode, use `/^[\p{L}'][ \p{L}'-]*[\p{L}]$/u`, however pretty forgiving.

Comment: And what about missing czech characters "řďťňŘĎŤŇ"? ;)

Comment: You should've included A-Z, like so:
^[A-Za-z ,.'-]+$

Comment: A-Z does not need to be included in the original example because the i modifier after the expression means ignore case.

Comment: This will include 'names' like ... or foo.'-asd. I think ^([a-z]+[,.]?[ ]?|[a-z]+['-]?)+$ this is will remove those cases.

Comment: This allows dot and spaces to be submitted and names

Comment: I use this, `^[\p{L} ,.'-]*$` which is working for Unicode too

Comment: `SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 'u'`

Comment: There are also multiple ways to get the basically same character that you would have to add in the special characters string, i.e.: \xc1A vs \u0301

Comment: I can't put this to work. It's accepting only the first name, as valid.

Comment: you does not handle white spaces

Comment: I do not find it correct because it accepts only spaces as a valid name

Comment: you should add "æ" to that;

Comment: So is `Иванов Иван Иванович` not a valid name here? You make false assumptions on the format of first and last name. It is probably better not to validate the name at all, apart from checking that it is empty.

Comment: If I enter multiple space only it accept it

Comment: will it work for non normalized characters?

Answer (score 141):

You make false assumptions on the format of first and last name. It is probably better not to validate the name at all, apart from checking that it is empty.

Comment: This is the only sane answer. See also https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/ .

Comment: Be careful of JavaScript or HTML injection attacks if you're not validating.

Comment: But you probably don't want to have a name with Emoji's (or character-based emoticons)

Comment: Can't have numbers or symbols in a name though, can we? We want a "Name" not a "@username" after alll.

Comment: @pragmateek Yes, it can. Apparently, states like Hawaii accept all symbols on a standard US keyboard, and others like Washington accept numbers. As Sjoerd said, it's better not to make false assumptions.

Comment: yeah hey, let's not be discriminatory against baby elon X Æ A-12!!!

Comment: The answer is only "sane" if you don't need to interact with any downstream systems (which you can't change) that are making false assumptions about names.

Comment: This is indeed a terrible question, so I'm upvoting this answer even though it's more of a comment.

Answer (score 66):

After going through all of these answers I found a way to build a tiny regex that supports most languages and only allows for word characters. It even supports some special characters like hyphens, spaces and apostrophes. I've tested in python and it supports the characters below:

```
^[\w'\-,.][^0-9_!¡?÷?¿/\\+=@#$%ˆ&*(){}|~<>;:[\]]{2,}$
```

Characters supported:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
áéíóúäëïöüÄ'
陳大文
łŁőŐűŰZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõøùúûüųū
ÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁ
ŃÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŲŪŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ.-
ñÑâê都道府県Федерации
আবাসযোগ্য জমির걸쳐 있는
```

Comment: Out of all the answers this one worked like a charm using ng 4.

Comment: Your regex fail on 2 characters string. I think this fixed it
`^[\w'\-,.]*[^_!¡?÷?¿\/\\+=@#$%ˆ&*(){}|~<>;:[\]]*$`

Comment: National characters are supported but not on the first position. I'd change expression to `^[^0-9_!¡?÷?¿/\\+=@#$%ˆ&*(){}|~<>;:[\]]{2,}$`

Comment: We have the common lastname Österreicher in Austria and it's invalid. Also according to regex101.com the forward slash needs to be escaped. I cannot recommend this...

Comment: So Emoji's are valid ?

Comment: You need to escape the `/` so that would be `^[\w'\-,.][^0-9_!¡?÷?¿\/\\+=@#$%ˆ&*(){}|~<>;:[\]]{2,}$`

Comment: @CodingYourLife "Österreicher" is matched by this RegEx.

Comment: This RegEx matches newlines which is incorrect! It also doesn't match `陳大文 `. I suggest `^[^\n0-9_!¡?÷?¿\/\\+=@#$%ˆ&*(){}|~<>;:[\]]{2,}$`

Comment: This will match even when national character is in first position @TOUDIdel : 
`/^[\p{L}'\-,.][^0-9_!¡?÷?¿/\\+=@#$%ˆ&*(){}|~<>;:[\]]{2,}$/u`

I have edited the original answer with this as it seems like a bug in the original regex.

Comment: At the least, html tags should be stripped.

Answer (score 47):

I have created a custom regex to deal with names:

I have tried these types of names and found working perfect

1. John Smith
2. John D'Largy
3. John Doe-Smith
4. John Doe Smith
5. Hector Sausage-Hausen
6. Mathias d'Arras
7. Martin Luther King
8. Ai Wong
9. Chao Chang
10. Alzbeta Bara

My RegEx looks like this:

```
^([a-zA-Z]{2,}\s[a-zA-Z]{1,}'?-?[a-zA-Z]{2,}\s?([a-zA-Z]{1,})?)
```

MVC4 Model:

```
[RegularExpression("^([a-zA-Z]{2,}\\s[a-zA-Z]{1,}'?-?[a-zA-Z]{2,}\\s?([a-zA-Z]{1,})?)", ErrorMessage = "Valid Charactors include (A-Z) (a-z) (' space -)") ]
```

**Please note the double `\\` for escape characters**

For those of you that are new to RegEx I thought I'd include a explanation.

```
^               // start of line
[a-zA-Z]{2,}    // will except a name with at least two characters
\s              // will look for white space between name and surname
[a-zA-Z]{1,}    // needs at least 1 Character
\'?-?           // possibility of **'** or **-** for double barreled and hyphenated surnames
[a-zA-Z]{2,}    // will except a name with at least two characters
\s?             // possibility of another whitespace
([a-zA-Z]{1,})? // possibility of a second surname
```

Comment: I have a unit test that tests several names, then several things that are not names. The not names list has 'test token' as the first entry. This matches that.

Comment: It's almost what i was looking for. I guess (maybe wrongly) that you are a french guy. And one case is not handle that you can encounter in French : composed names, like Jean-Pierre, Marie-Charlotte, etc...I'm new to reg exp but i guess a -? like you did for last name, in between the 2 first words, could do the job.

Comment: Hi Linpter, Not French, however I do have a French name. Yes. I have not tested this, however you should be able to add the - in the first  [ ] so change:
 ^([a-zA-Z]{2,}\s[a-zA-z]{1,}'?-?[a-zA-Z]{2,}\s?([a-zA-Z]{1,})?) 
TO:
 ^([a-zA-Z -]{2,}\s[a-zA-z]{1,}'?-?[a-zA-Z]{2,}\s?([a-zA-Z]{1,})?)

Comment: Does not work for abbreviations like. John F. Kennedy

Comment: you should be able to add "." in the line \'?-? and add period that might catch this.

example '?-?.? 
note that this is not tested and going on 3 year old knowledge

Comment: This doesn't work with names such as Fabián, Julián, Ramírez, López. All pretty common names and last names in Latin America.

Answer (score 21):

I've tried almost everything on this page, then I decided to modify the most voted answer which ended up working best. Simply matches all languages and includes `.,-'`  characters.

Here it is:

```
/^[\p{L} ,.'-]+$/u
```

Comment: Probably the most sensed answer here. This Regex will block only numbers but will accomodate various name formats. However if you care about Internet Explorer 11 this one uses the unicode Regex prototype, which is not available in old browsers

Comment: You might improve this by disallowing single-letter names `^[\p{L} ,.'-]{2.}$`. So `Jo" is OK but not "J".

Comment: Your regex matches the following strings: `.-..,.,..,.,-,.,.,.,-----.,.,.,.,.,.,---.,.,.,`, `GSDDSGSDHSDBKSDGFDPKNDRJFBDFDbdfbdfkbjdfDFGDFG`, `'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''`, `.'.'.'-'.'.'.'bdf.'-.'.'-'.'.'.sdgscdbsf'.''..''.---`, `sdgk                                ldksjfgklsdjgklsdjgklsdjklBCBCBCBbjkds`, `'-shS'-xfbX,,,,,xdg'''xx'cxb,--'',,---xfvb,.ZgzdzxSA          safgasf`. To put it bluntly, your regex is terrible. It matches almost all full-length sentences.

Answer (score 16):

I have searched and searched and played and played with it and although it is not perfect it may help others making the attempt to validate first and last names that have been provided as one variable.

In my case, that variable is $name.

I used the following code for my PHP:

```
    if (preg_match('/\b([A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1,30}[- ]{0,1}|[A-Z]{1}[- \']{1}[A-Z]{0,1}  
    [a-z]{1,30}[- ]{0,1}|[a-z]{1,2}[ -\']{1}[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1,30}){2,5}/', $name)  
    # there is no space line break between in the above "if statement", any that   
    # you notice or perceive are only there for formatting purposes.  
    # 
    # pass - successful match - do something
    } else {
    # fail - unsuccessful match - do something
```

I am learning RegEx myself but I do have the explanation for the code as provided by RegEx buddy.
Here it is:

Assert position at a word boundary «\b»

Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
«([A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1,30}[- ]{0,1}|[A-Z]{1}[- \']{1}[A-Z]{0,1}[a-z]{1,30}[- ]{0,1}|[a-z]{1,2}[ -\']{1}[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1,30}){2,5}»

Between 2 and 5 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{2,5}»

******* I NEED SOME HELP HERE WITH UNDERSTANDING THE RAMIFICATIONS OF THIS NOTE *******

Note: I repeated the capturing group itself.  The group will capture only the last iteration.  Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations. «{2,5}»

Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1,30}[- ]{0,1}»

Match a single character in the range between “A” and “Z” «[A-Z]{1}»

Exactly 1 times «{1}»

Match a single character in the range between “a” and “z” «[a-z]{1,30}»

Between one and 30 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{1,30}»

Match a single character present in the list “- ” «[- ]{0,1}»

Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{0,1}»

Or match regular expression number 2 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «[A-Z]{1}[- \']{1}[A-Z]{0,1}[a-z]{1,30}[- ]{0,1}»

Match a single character in the range between “A” and “Z” «[A-Z]{1}»

Exactly 1 times «{1}»

Match a single character present in the list below «[- \']{1}»

Exactly 1 times «{1}»

One of the characters “- ” «- »  A ' character «\'»

Match a single character in the range between “A” and “Z” «[A-Z]{0,1}»

Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{0,1}»

Match a single character in the range between “a” and “z” «[a-z]{1,30}»

Between one and 30 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{1,30}»

Match a single character present in the list “- ” «[- ]{0,1}»

Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{0,1}»

Or match regular expression number 3 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «[a-z]{1,2}[ -\']{1}[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1,30}»

Match a single character in the range between “a” and “z” «[a-z]{1,2}»

Between one and 2 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{1,2}»

Match a single character in the range between “ ” and “'” «[ -\']{1}»

Exactly 1 times «{1}»

Match a single character in the range between “A” and “Z” «[A-Z]{1}»

Exactly 1 times «{1}»

Match a single character in the range between “a” and “z” «[a-z]{1,30}»

Between one and 30 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{1,30}»

I know this validation totally assumes that every person filling out the form has a western name and that may eliminates the vast majority of folks in the world. However, I feel like this is a step in the proper direction. Perhaps this regular expression is too basic for the gurus to address simplistically or maybe there is some other reason that I was unable to find the above code in my searches.  I spent way too long trying to figure this bit out, you  will probably notice just how foggy my mind is on all this if you look at my test names below.

I tested the code on the following names and the results are in parentheses to the right of each name.

1. STEVE SMITH  (fail)
2. Stev3 Smith  (fail)
3. STeve Smith  (fail)
4. Steve SMith  (fail)
5. Steve Sm1th  (passed on the Steve Sm)
6. d'Are to Beaware (passed on the Are to Beaware)
7. Jo Blow  (passed)
8. Hyoung Kyoung Wu (passed)
9. Mike O'Neal (passed)
10. Steve Johnson-Smith (passed)
11. Jozef-Schmozev Hiemdel (passed)
12. O Henry Smith  (passed)
13. Mathais d'Arras  (passed)
14. Martin Luther King Jr  (passed)
15. Downtown-James Brown (passed)
16. Darren McCarty (passed)
17. George De FunkMaster (passed)
18. Kurtis B-Ball Basketball (passed)
19. Ahmad el Jeffe (passed)

If you have basic names, there must be more than one up to five for the above code to work, that are similar to those that I used during testing, this code might be for you.

If you have any improvements, please let me know.  I am just in the early stages (first few months of figuring out RegEx.

Thanks and good luck,
Steve

Comment: Would things like "The Fourth" or "IV" work with this?

Comment: Doesn't work with "Björk Guðmundsdóttir"

Comment: '/^[\p{L}\s\'-]+' and I tested it against the following 4 names: king henry vi
Björk Guðmundsdótt
Mike O'Connell Sr
 Steve Kinzey only king henry vi, Björk Guðmundsdótt
and Mike O'Connell Sr were returned.  Steve Kinzey was not.

Answer (score 9):

First name would be

```
"([a-zA-Z]{3,30}\s*)+"
```

If you need the whole first name part to be shorter than 30 letters, you need to check that seperately, I think. The expression `".{3,30}"` should do that.

Your last name requirements would translate into

```
"[a-zA-Z]{3,30}"
```

but you should check these. There are plenty of last names containing spaces.

Comment: Does this checks for spaces between?

Comment: What about _O'Connor_? The apostrophe needs to be included too.

Comment: Pretty incomplete. First name could be "Jean-Claude" with hyphen. Last name could be "D'arc" with quote. Plus, what if "François" is the first name?

Comment: What about "Al"? Valid first name. Just two letters. What about Chinese, Russian, Hindi names? What about European names?

Comment: this wouldnt work for a lot of non-english or (non-latin?) names

Comment: This will also accept string with 60 length or any string of length 30*X, X = 1,2,3,4....

Answer (score 9):

This regex work for me (was using in Angular 8) :

```
([a-zA-Z',.-]+( [a-zA-Z',.-]+)*){2,30}
```

[image]

It will be invalid if there is:-

> 1. Any whitespace start or end of the name
> 2. Got symbols e.g. @
> 3. Less than 2 or more than 30

Example invalid First Name (whitespace)

[image]

Example valid First Name :

[image]

Comment: What about 'Björk Guðmundsdóttir'?

Comment: Even with the Unicode version this passes two character names alone - i.e. "ab". I think there should be at least a two-word requirement

Comment: returning --===+00 as valid name

Answer (score 8):

As maček said:

**Don't forget about names like:**

> Mathias d'Arras
>
> Martin Luther King, Jr.
>
> Hector Sausage-Hausen

**and to remove cases like:**

> ..Mathias
>
> Martin king,   Jr.-

This will cover more cases:

```
^([a-z]+[,.]?[ ]?|[a-z]+['-]?)+$
```

Comment: If I want to limit my character length so what might be the code for that ?

Comment: Yes Martin Luther King Jr. returns as a match, and so does King Henry the Eighth.

Comment: Here's a regex with tests for this one: https://regex101.com/r/mejVRR/5

Answer (score 8):

I'm working on the app that validates International Passports (ICAO). We support only english characters. While most foreign national characters can be represented by a character in the Latin alphabet e.g. è by e, there are several national characters that require an extra letter to represent them such as the German umlaut which requires an ‘e’ to be added to the letter e.g. ä by ae.

This is the JavaScript Regex for the first and last names we use:

```
/^[a-zA-Z '.-]*$/
```

[The max number of characters on the international passport is up to 31](http://dfat.gov.au/about-us/publications/corporate/passports/online-passport-information/Policy/Names/Nameacceptability/index.htm).
We use maxlength="31" to better word error messages instead of including it in the regex.

Here is a snippet from our code in AngularJS 1.6 with form and error handling:

```js
class PassportController {
  constructor() {
    this.details = {};
    // English letters, spaces and the following symbols ' - . are allowed
    // Max length determined by ng-maxlength for better error messaging
    this.nameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z '.-]*$/;
  }
}

angular.module('akyc', ['ngMessages'])
  .controller('PassportController', PassportController);
```

```css
 
.has-error p[ng-message] {
  color: #bc111e;
}

.tip {
  color: #535f67;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.6/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

<main ng-app="akyc" ng-controller="PassportController as $ctrl">
  <form name="$ctrl.form">

    <div name="lastName" ng-class="{ 'has-error': $ctrl.form.lastName.$invalid} ">
        <label for="pp-last-name">Surname</label>
        <div class="tip">Exactly as it appears on your passport</div>
        <div ng-messages="$ctrl.form.lastName.$error" ng-if="$ctrl.form.$submitted" id="last-name-error">
          <p ng-message="required">Please enter your last name</p>
          <p ng-message="maxlength">This field can be at most 31 characters long</p>
          <p ng-message="pattern">Only English letters, spaces and the following symbols ' - . are allowed</p>
        </div>
        
        <input type="text" id="pp-last-name" ng-model="$ctrl.details.lastName" name="lastName"
               class="form-control" required ng-pattern="$ctrl.nameRegex" ng-maxlength="31" aria-describedby="last-name-error" />
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Test</button>

  </form>
</main>
```

Comment: @danieltakeshi you didn't use my Regex. Use this: /^[a-zA-Z '.-]*$/

Comment: This regex will accept an empty string or a bunch of spaces as a valid name. Also strings such as "...", "---", " .-' .-' .-' "

Answer (score 8):

I didn't find any answer helpful for me simply because users can pick a non-english name and simple regex are not helpful. In fact it's actually very hard to find the right expression that works for all languages.

Instead, I picked a different approach and negated all characters that should not be in the name for the valid match. Below pattern negates numerical, special characters, control characters and '\', '/'

Final regex
without punctuations: ["] ['] [,] [.], etc. :

```
^([^\p{N}\p{S}\p{C}\p{P}]{2,20})$
```

with punctuations:

```
^([^\p{N}\p{S}\p{C}\\\/]{2,20})$
```

With this, all these names are valid:

```
alex junior
沐宸
Nick
Sarah's Jane ---> with punctuation support
ביממה
حقیقت
Виктория
```

And following names become invalid:

```
 Maria
k
١١١١١
123John
```

This means all names that don't have numerical characters, emojis, \ and are between 2-20 characters are allowed. You can edit the above regex if you want to add more characters to exclusion list.

To get more information about available patterns to include / exclude checkout this:
https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop

Comment: Thank you ! I will continue testing regex without ponctuations, seems great

Comment: Poor Gukesh, how will he enter his name on your system? https://ratings.fide.com/profile/46616543

Answer (score 7):

Read almost all highly voted posts (only some are good). After understanding the problem in detail & doing research, here are the tight regexes:

1). `^[A-Z][a-z]*(([,.] |[ '-])[A-Za-z][a-z]*)*(\.?)$`

- name `Z` is allowed contrary to the assumption made by some in the thread.
- No leading or trailing spaces are allowed, empty string is NOT allowed, string containing only spaces is NOT allowed
- Supports English alphabets only
- Supports hyphens (`Some-Foobarbaz-name`, `Some foobarbaz-Name`), apostrophes (`David D'Costa`, `David D'costa`, `David D'costa R'Costa p'costa`), periods (`Dr. L. John`, `Robert Downey Jr.`, `Md. K. P. Asif`) and commas (`Martin Luther, Jr.`).
- First alphabet of only the first word of a name MUST be capital.
  **NOT Allowed**: `John sTeWaRT`, `JOHN STEWART`, `Md. KP Asif`, `John Stewart PhD`
  **Allowed**: `John Stewart`, `John stewart`, `Md. K P Asif`
  *you can easily modify this condition*.

If you also want to allow names like `Queen Elizabeth 2` or `Henry IV`:
2). `^[A-Z][a-z]*(([,.] |[ '-])[A-Za-z][a-z]*)*([.]?| (-----)| [1-9][0-9]*)$`

replace `-----` with roman numeral's regex (which itself is long) OR you can use this alternative regex which is based on KISS philosophy `[IVXLCDM]+` (here `I`, `V`, `X`, ... in ANY random order will satisfy the regex).

---

I personally suggest to use this regex:
3). `^[A-Z][a-z]*(([,.] |[ '-])[A-Za-z][a-z]*)*(\.?)( [IVXLCDM]+)?$`
Feel free to try this regex [**HERE**](https://regex101.com/r/7SJbOB/1) & make any modifications of your choice.

I have provided with tight regex which covers every possible name I found on my research with no bug. Modify these regexes to relax some of the unwanted constraints.

---

**[UPDATE - March, 2022]**

Here are 4 more regexes:

`^[A-Za-z]+(([,.] |[ '-])[A-Za-z]+)*([.,'-]?)$`

`^((([,.'-]| )(?<!( {2}|[,.'-]{2})))*[A-Za-z]+)+[,.'-]?$`

`^( ([A-Za-z,.'-]+|$))+|([A-Za-z,.'-]+( |$))+$`

`^(([ ,.'-](?<!( {2}|[,.'-]{2})))*[A-Za-z])+[ ,.'-]?$`

It's been a while since I looked back at these 4 regexes so I forgot their specifications. These 4 regexes are not tight, unlike the previous ones but do the job very well. These regexes distinguish 3 parts of a name: English alphabet, space and special character. Which one you need out of these 4 depends on your answer (**Yes**/**No**) to these questions:

1. have at least 1 alphabet?
2. can start with a space or a special character?
3. can end with a space or a special character?
4. are 2 consecutive spaces allowed?
5. are 2 consecutive special characters allowed?

**Note:** name validation should ONLY serve as a warning NOT a necessity a name should fulfill because there is no fixed naming pattern, if there is one it can change overnight and thus, any tight regex you come across will become obsolete somewhere in future.

Comment: `^[A-Za-z][a-z]*(([,.] |[ '-])[A-Za-z][a-z]*)*(\.?)( [IVXLCDM]+)?$` removes the constraint of first alphabet of the first word of a name to be capital.
To further modify the regex to ignore case, replace both `[A-Za-z][a-z]*` with `[A-Za-z]+`

Comment: This regex works only for English alphabets as mentioned in the post.

Comment: My friend's last name is DeBiasi, which wouldn't be permitted by the regexes above. He lives in the US.

Comment: @Christoph in that case you can make a slight modification to the regex to not take the case of an alphabet into account, right?
But I certainly missed a case like "DeBiasi", never came across any name like this before. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Christoph I edited the answer to add 4 more regexes, but I forgot what these 4 regexes were supposed to do. See if they meet your purpose.

Answer (score 6):

There is one issue with the top voted answer here which recommends this regex:

```
/^[a-z ,.'-]+$/i
```

It takes spaces only as a valid name!

The best solution in my opinion is to add a negative look forward to the beginning:

```
/^(?!\s)([a-z ,.'-]+)$/i
```

Answer (score 4):

I use:

```
/^(?:[\u00c0-\u01ffa-zA-Z'-]){2,}(?:\s[\u00c0-\u01ffa-zA-Z'-]{2,})+$/i
```

And test for maxlength using some other means

Answer (score 3):

```
^\p{L}{2,}$
```

^ asserts position at start of a line.

\p{L} matches any kind of letter from any language

{2,} Quantifier — Matches between 2 and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

$ asserts position at the end of a line

So it should be a name in any language containing at least 2 letters(or symbols) without numbers or other characters.

Comment: keep in mind that some characters like ' and - are valid in names.

Answer (score 2):

If you are searching a simplest way, just check almost 2 words.

```
/^[^\s]+( [^\s]+)+$/
```

**Valid names**

- John Doe
- pedro alberto ch
- Ar. Gen
- Mathias d'Arras
- Martin Luther King, Jr.

**No valid names**

- John
- 
- 陳大文

Answer (score -1):

So, with customer we create this crazy regex:

```
(^$)|(^([^\-!#\$%&\(\)\*,\./:;\?@\[\\\]_\{\|\}¨ˇ“”€\+<=>§°\d\s¤®™©]| )+$)
```

Answer (score -1):

For first and last names theres are really only 2 things you should be looking for:

1. Length
2. Content

Here is my regular expression:

var regex = /^[A-Za-z-,]{3,20}?=.*\d)/

**1. Length**

Here the {3,20} constrains the length of the string to be between 3 and 20 characters.

**2. Content**

The information between the square brackets [A-Za-z] allows uppercase and lowercase characters. All subsequent symbols (-,.) are also allowed.