# What "validation logic" should I test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, rspec

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and RSpec 2. I would like to know what "validation logic" I should test. That is, if in my model I have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :firstname
    :presence => true
end
```

**What should I test of the following?**

1. "should *have* a valid first name"
2. "should *not have* a valid first name"

**Or should I test both?**

Comment: In the question I am assuming you are interested in specifically testing the "is present" aspect of the name and not any other "validness". Maybe you should clarify that.

Answer (score 3):

You can test both by simply doing this:

```
it "should validate presence of" do
   should validate_presence_of :firstname
end
```

Take a look at the [shoulda matchers](http://rdoc.info/github/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/master/Shoulda/Matchers/ActiveModel%3avalidate_presence_of) for all such standard Rails Validation.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should not test both. This will be enough:

```
describe User do
  it { should validate_presence_of(:firstname) }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is basically no algorithm for validating names, because the form of names is incredibly culture-centric. So, really you should avoid complex validations for something like a person's name. Some places/cultures don't have last names, for example, so even validating their presence isn't proper. There's a whole list of other examples that make validating names a really bad idea. For more information on the issue of validating names itself, see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362567/java-regex-for-full-name/7363159#7363159).

That being said, in general, when validating any field, I test both valid and invalid data. I make sure that, when I set a field to a valid value, that the `.valid?` method returns `true`, and when it's invalid, that it returns `false`.

Typically you don't need to do a long list, you just need to test

- A typical valid and invalid example
- A few edge cases

Answer (score 0):

you can also test for specific values:

```
describe User do    
    context "validations" do
        it { should_not allow_value("admin").for(:firstname) }
        it { should allow_value("JohnDoe").for(:firstname) }
    end    
end
```