# Can I make a loop if the user doesn't give me string as an input?

Tags: c#

For example if I ask the user to give me his name (string) and he writes numbers, symbols or if he press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> I want a loop to tell him to write string in order to continue. I made a loop for integers but I don't know how to make for strings

```
Console.Write("Please enter the name of the student: ");
//here I made the input to turn into Capitals
name = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper(); 

Console.Write("Please enter their student number: ");
// here I set a condition order to continue. First the input must be integer and second it must be positive
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out id)||id<0)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.Write("The value must be of integer type, try again: ");
    Console.ResetColor();
}
```

Comment: Use regex to validate your string

Comment: Check this for validation of names using Regex, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385701/regular-expression-for-first-and-last-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Console.Write("Please enter the name of the student: ");
//here I made the input to turn into Capitals
name = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper(); 
if (Regex.IsMatch(name, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$")) { // If letters only
 // Do something
}else{
 Console.WriteLine("Name must contain letters only");
}

Console.Write("Please enter their student number: ");
// here I set a condition order to continue. First the input must be integer and second it must be positive
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out id)||id<0)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.Write("The value must be of integer type, try again: ");
    Console.ResetColor();
}
```

This should check for letters only.

Comment: Because i am new to programming can you help me insert the code properly. I tried it, but i couldn't make a loop until the user enters correct input. how can i write it properly to my code?

Comment: Revised the code to basically check if `name` contains only letters.