# Regex to grab full firstname and first letter of last name

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a list of users grabbed by the `Etc` Ruby library:

> Thomas_J_Perkins
>
> Jennifer_Scanner
>
> Amanda_K_Loso
>
> Aaron_Cole
>
> Mark_L_Lamb

What I need to do is grab the full first name, skip the middle name (if given), and grab the first character of the last name. The output should look like this:

> Thomas P
>
> Jennifer S
>
> Amanda L
>
> Aaron C
>
> Mark L

I'm not sure how to do this, I've tried grabbing all of the characters: `/\w+/` but that will grab everything.

Comment: Define "first name" and "last name". In what culture? Don't assume that a first name occurs first; You can inadvertently insult a customer by not processing their name correctly. Read "[ask]" including the links, and "[mcve]". We expect to see evidence of your effort. As is it looks like you haven't tried and want us to write the code for you, which is off-topic, or to write a tutorial for you, which again is off-topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't always need regular expressions.

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions." Now they have two problems. *Jamie Zawinski*

You can do it with some simple Ruby code

```
string = "Mark_L_Lamb"
string.split('_').first + ' ' + string.split('_').last[0]
=> "Mark L"
```

Comment: Was just typing the same.

Comment: Good answer, but calling `string.split("_")` twice is needless.

Comment: @amdouglas Would that still work even if there's no middle initial?

Comment: @JasonBorne yes, it takes the full first word and the first letter of the last word.  It doesn't care if you have two or three words.

Answer (score 6):

I think its simpler without regex:

```
array = "Thomas_J_Perkins".split("_") # split at _
array.first + " " + array.last[0] # .first prints first name .last[0] prints first char of last name
#=> "Thomas P"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
^([^\W_]+)(?:_[^\W_]+)*_([^\W_])[^\W_]*$
```

And replace with `\1_\2`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fA5yE1/1)

The `[^\W_]` matches a letter or a digit. If you want to only match letters, replace `[^\W_]` with `\p{L}`.

```
^(\p{L}+)(?:_\p{L}+)*_(\p{L})\p{L}*$
```

See [updated demo](https://regex101.com/r/fA5yE1/2)

The point is to match and capture the first chunk of letters up to the first `_` (with `(\p{L}+)`), then match 0+ sequences of `_` + letters inside (with `(?:_\p{L}+)*_`) and then match and capture the last word first letter (with `(\p{L})`) and then match the rest of the string (with `\p{L}*`).

NOTE: replace `^` with `\A` and `$` with `\z` if you have independent strings (as in Ruby `^` matches the start of a line and `$` matches the end of the line).

[Ruby code](http://ideone.com/kewb1y):

```
s.sub(/^(\p{L}+)(?:_\p{L}+)*_(\p{L})\p{L}*$/, "\\1_\\2")
```

Comment: [Please don't restrict names to only word characters.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385701/regular-expression-for-first-and-last-name/32517316#32517316) `[^_]` instead of `[^\W_]` or `\p{L}` is perfectly acceptable here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the don't-use-a-regex-for-this camp.

```
str1 = "Alexander_Graham_Bell"
str2 = "Sylvester_Grisby"

"#{str1[0...str1.index('_')]} #{str1[str1.rindex('_')+1]}"
  #=> "Alexander B"
"#{str2[0...str2.index('_')]} #{str2[str2.rindex('_')+1]}"
  #=> "Sylvester G"
```

or

```
first, last = str1.split(/_.+_|_/)
  #=> ["Alexander", "Bell"] 
first+' '+last[0]
  #=> "Alexander B" 

first, last = str2.split(/_.+_|_/)
  #=> ["Sylvester", "Grisby"] 
first+' '+last[0]
  #=> "Sylvester G"
```

but if you insist...

```
r = /
    (.+?)     # match any characters non-greedily in capture group 1
    (?=_)     # match an underscore in a positive lookahead 
    (?:.*)    # match any characters greedily in a non-capture group 
    (?:_)     # match an underscore in a non-capture group
    (.)       # match any character in capture group 2
    /x        # free-spacing regex definition mode

str1 =~ r
$1+' '+$2
  #=> "Alexander B"

str2 =~ r
$1+' '+$2
  #=> "Sylvester G"
```

You can of course write

```
r = /(.+?)(?=_)(?:.*)(?:_)(.)/
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt:

```
/([a-zA-Z]+)_([a-zA-Z]+_)?([a-zA-Z])/
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/d9E31KiPmQ)

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if this works:

```
/^([^_]+)(?:_\w)?_(\w)/
```

And then you'll have to combine the first and second matches into the format you want. I don't know Ruby, so I can't help you there.

Answer (score 0):

And another attempt using a replacement method:

```
result = subject.gsub(/^([^_]+)(?:_[^_])?_([^_])[^_]+$/, '\1 \2')
```

We capture the entire string, with the relevant parts in capturing groups.  Then just return the two captured groups

Answer (score 0):

using the split method is much better

```
full_names.map do |full_name|
   parts = full_name.split('_').values_at(0,-1)
   parts.last.slice!(1..-1)
   parts.join(' ')
end
```

Comment: I suggest `first, last = full_name.split('_').values_at(0,-1); first+last[0]`.

Answer (score -1):

/^[A-Za-z]{5,15}\s[A-Za-z]{1}]$/i
This will have the following criteria: 
5-15 characters for first name then a whitespace and finally a single character for last name.

Comment: [Never, ever restrict names to word characters.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32517316/1222951) Also, people named "Bill" or "Paul" or "Anne" might have a problem with the 5-15 character criteria. And what's that `\s` doing in your pattern anyway?

Comment: \s denotes a whitespace so that there is a white space between the first name and the last name.  If length is an an issue then you can use {,upperLimit} anytime.

Comment: The point is, your pattern doesn't work because of the `\s`. You want to match an underscore, not a space.

Comment: In that case: /^[A-Za-z]{2,15}[_]{1}[A-Za-z]{1}]$/i

Comment: I'm starting to think that you misunderstood OP's question. Your pattern isn't supposed to match names like "Mark L", it's supposed to turn "Mark_L_Lamb" _into_ "Mark L".