# Javascript Fullname Regex Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have been using a regex code for fullnames in JavaScript and the pattern looks like this :  `/(\w)\s(\w)/`  . The problem is that this pattern accepts numbers which I don't won't in the users fullname. So,I need a pattern that accepts a space after the first name and accepts a second name after the space and has a limit of 30 characters but does not accept numbers. I don't know how to create a regex pattern so any help is appreciated.

This is what the code looks like now:

```js
    if(name.match(/(\w)\s(\w)/)){
        flagOne = true;
    }
```

Comment: see [regular-expression-for-first-and-last-name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385701/regular-expression-for-first-and-last-name)

Comment: Have a look at this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385701/regular-expression-for-first-and-last-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following pattern to match only alphabetical characters (be aware, that you are now not allowing special characters like `çöäüèéà` or punctuation characters like `'` or `-`):

```
/^([A-Za-z]+?)\s([A-Za-z]+?)$/
```

The length of the full string cannot be measured in this form, but can be easily read out with JavaScript:

```
name.length;
```

**Here is an example in JavaScript:**

```
var name = "Test Name";
if(name.match(/^([A-Za-z]+?)\s([A-Za-z]+?)$/) && name.length <= 30) {
    console.log("name is valid.");
}
```

*Like @gaetanoM pointet out in the comments, you could also use a more sophisticated regular expression like it is described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40056630/3233827).*