# Full name regex expression not working

Tags: regex, dart, flutter

Im trying to use a regex expression to validate a full name for a textfield form in flutter but i cant figure out why it isnt working.

The expression i found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385701/regular-expression-for-first-and-last-name) `/^[a-z ,.'-]+$/i` is failing for any entry i give.

The code i'm using in dart for my flutter app is:

```
final RegExp nameExp = new RegExp(r"/^[a-z ,.'-]+$", caseSensitive: false);
```

Can anyone see what i'm missing?

Update: so the regex was allowing most things and wasnt quite correct, what worked for me was `r"^([a-zA-Z]{2,}\s[a-zA-z]{1,}'?-?[a-zA-Z]{2,}\s?([a-zA-Z]{1,})?)"` with the accepted answer below

Comment: Can you give us fail/success case tests?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove slash `/` delimiters and add the Dart delimiters : `r'^[a-z ,.'-]+$ '`

Comment: How do i include the `'` in the middle of the regex?

Comment: can use  \  before any special characher

Comment: ive tried this but it wont compile with `r'^[a-z ,.\'-]+$'`

Comment: Don't you get an error message when it doesn't compile?

Comment: try  `r ' ^[a-z ,\.\'-]+$' `  if not work please write some name target with you to test it

Comment: So the IDE looks like https://i.imgur.com/qnUhpNi.png, and i get the errors, `Unterminated string literal.` `Expected to find ')'.`

Comment: RegExp namex = new RegExp ( r"^[a-z ,.\'-]+$") ;

Comment: This stops the error but now it just allows anything but an empty string

Comment: Can you give us fail/success case tests?

Comment: currently typing nothing fails, and `w` `www` `www www` `w w` all pass

Comment: can add success case test of Full name example

Comment: ok so the regex was wrong but you solved my initial issues so thanks, the regex that worked was `r"^([a-zA-Z]{2,}\s[a-zA-z]{1,}'?-?[a-zA-Z]{2,}\s?([a-zA-Z]{1,})?)"` if you want your answer to be absolutely correct, i will upvote and say is correct either way

Comment: @Wazza `A-z` must be changed to `A-Z`, [or it will match `_`, `\``, and some more non-letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926).

Answer (score 4):

use below method for validate full name

```
String fullNameValidate(String fullName) {
  String patttern = r'^[a-z A-Z,.\-]+$';
  RegExp regExp = new RegExp(patttern);
  if (fullName.length == 0) {
    return 'Please enter full name';
  } else if (!regExp.hasMatch(fullName)) {
    return 'Please enter valid full name';
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern namePattern = r"^[a-zA-Z]+(([',. -][a-zA-Z ])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$"
RegExp nameRegex = RegExp(namePattern, caseSensitive: false);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering; please make sure you read (or at least peruse) https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting so that your answers stand out better.

Comment: Welcome. Thanks for your contribution. Consider adding an explanation to improve quality, and long term value. SO discourages code only Answers. Regex solutions are particularly dense and difficult to understand without explanation, especially for newcomers to regex.