# Regex for first name

Tags: c#, regex

I am quite new to regex thing and need regex for first name which satisfies following conditions:

1. First Name must contain letters only. It may contain spaces, hyphens, or apostrophes.
2. It must begin with letters.
3. All other characters and numbers are not valid.
4. Special characters `‘` and `–` cannot be together (e.g. John’-s is not allowed)
5. An alphabet should be present before and after the special characters `‘` and `–` (e.g. John ‘s is not allowed)
6. Two consecutive spaces are not allowed (e.g. Annia  St is not allowed)

Can anyone help? I tried this `^([a-z]+['-]?[ ]?|[a-z]+['-]?)*?[a-z]$` but it's not working as expected.

Comment: Your first sentence is confusing: "First Name must contain letters only. It may contain spaces, hyphens, or apostrophes."

Comment: Is it easier to provide an appropriate answer if you provide examples that should and should not match.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regular expression for first and last name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385701/regular-expression-for-first-and-last-name)

Comment: This is not a duplicate as posted

Comment: You don't _need_ a regex. You _need_ to parse names and you think you need regex. Please don't use regex for this task even though it is appealing due to its possible conciseness. However its unclearness will kill you soon or later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regexes are notoriously difficult to write and maintain.

One technique that I've used over the years is to annotate my regexes by using named capture groups.  It's not perfect, but can greatly help with the readability and maintainability of your regex.

Here is a regex that meets your requirements.

```
^(?<firstchar>(?=[A-Za-z]))((?<alphachars>[A-Za-z])|(?<specialchars>[A-Za-z]['-](?=[A-Za-z]))|(?<spaces> (?=[A-Za-z])))*$
```

It is split down into the following parts:

1) `(?<firstchar>(?=[A-Za-z]))` This ensures the first character is an alpha character, upper or lowercase.

2) `(?<alphachars>[A-Za-z])` We allow more alpha chars.

3) `(?<specialchars>[A-Za-z]['-](?=[A-Za-z]))` We allow special characters, but only with an alpha character before and after.

4) `(?<spaces> (?=[A-Za-z]))` We allow spaces, but only one space, which must be followed by alpha characters.

You should use a testing tool when writing regexes, I'd recommend https://regex101.com/

You can see from the screenshot below how this regex performs.

Take the regex I've given you, run it in https://regex101.com/ with samples you'd like to match against, and tweak it to fit your requirements.  Hopefully I've given you enough information to be self sufficient in customising it to your needs.

[image]

You can use this link to run the regex https://regex101.com/r/O2wFfi/1/

## Edit

I've updated to address the issue in your comment, rather than just give you the code, I will explain the problem and how I fixed it.

For your example "Sam D'Joe", if we run the original regex, the following happens.

```
^(?<firstchar>[A-Za-z])((?<alphachars>[A-Za-z])|(?<specialchars>[A-Za-z]['-][A-Za-z])|(?<spaces> [A-Za-z]))*$
```

1) `^` matches the start of the string
[image]

2) `(?<firstchar>[A-Za-z])` matches the first character
[image]

3) `(?<alphachars>[A-Za-z])` matches every character up to the space
[image]

4) `(?<spaces> [A-Za-z])` matches the space and the subsequent alpha char
[image]

### Matches consume the characters that they match

This is where we run into a problem. Our "specialchars" part of the regex matches an alpha char, our special char and then another alpha char (`(?<specialchars>[A-Za-z]['-](?=[A-Za-z]))`).

The thing you need to know about regexes, is each time you match a character, that character is then consumed.  We've already matched the alpha char before the special character, so our regex will never match.

Each step actually looks like this:

1) `^` matches the start of the string
[image]

2) `(?<firstchar>[A-Za-z])` matches the first character
[image]

3) `(?<alphachars>[A-Za-z])` matches every character up to the space
[image]

4) `(?<spaces> [A-Za-z])` matches the space and the subsequent alpha char
[image]

and then we're left with the following
[image]

We cannot match this, because one of our rules is "An alphabet should be present before and after the special characters ‘ and –".

### Lookahead

Regex has a concept called "lookahead".  A lookahead allows you to match a character without consuming it!

The syntax for a lookahead is `?=` followed by what you want to match.  E.g. `?=[A-Z]` would look ahead for a single character that is an uppercase letter.

We can fix our regex, by using lookaheads.

1) `^` matches the start of the string
[image]

2) `(?<firstchar>[A-Za-z])` matches the first character
[image]

3) `(?<alphachars>[A-Za-z])` matches every character up to the space
[image]

4) We now change our "spaces" regex, to lookahead to the alpha char, so we don't consume it.  We change `(?<spaces> [A-Za-z])` to `(?<spaces> ?=[A-Za-z])`.  This matches the space and looks ahead to the subsequent alpha char, but doesn't consume it.
[image]

5) `(?<specialchars>[A-Za-z]['-][A-Za-z])` matches the alpha char, the special char, and the subsequent alpha char.
[image]

6) We use a wildcard to repeat matching our previous 3 rules multiple times, and we match until the end of the line.
[image]

I also added lookaheads to the "firstchar", "specialchars" and "spaces" capture groups, I've bolded the changes below.

^(?<firstchar>**(?=**[A-Za-z]**)**)((?<alphachars>[A-Za-z])|(?<specialchars>[A-Za-z]['-]**(?=**[A-Za-z]**)**)|(?<spaces> **(?=**[A-Za-z]**)**))*$

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and explanation which indeed is quite helpful for novice like me. Unfortunately, it didn't work for "Sam D'Joe"

Comment: @SumitSingh, I've updated my answer to fix the problem, but also explain what was wrong and how I fixed it.  Please take a look, it's important to know about lookaheads when using regexes, I hope you find it helpful.

Answer (score 5):

This short regex should do it `^([a-zA-Z]+?)([-\s'][a-zA-Z]+)*?$` ,

- `([a-zA-Z]+?)` - Means the String should start with alphabets.
- `([-\s'][a-zA-Z]+)*?` - Means the string must have hyphen,space or apostrophe followed by alphabets.[image]
- `^` and `$`  - denote start and end of string

Here's the [link](https://regex101.com/r/jrBhVS/6) to regex demo.

Comment: Hey...It worked..Thank you. I also tried creating one by my own--> ^([a-zA-Z]+[-'\s]?)*?[a-zA-Z]$ which also looks to be working fine. Still not sure how to Unit Test it..:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
^[^- '](?=(?![A-Z]?[A-Z]))(?=(?![a-z]+[A-Z]))(?=(?!.*[A-Z][A-Z]))(?=(?!.*[- '][- '.]))(?=(?!.*[.][-'.]))[A-Za-z- '.]{2,}$
```

[image]
[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nMStwW/1)