# How to delete an object in a json array element?

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

Let's say I have this json format:

```
[
    {
       "firstName": "John", 
       "lastName": "Doe"
    }
]
```

and I want to delete the "lastName", how can I do that?

So far I have this query and it works, but the problem is it adds another array

```
UPDATE person
SET 
    field = jsonb_set(field::jsonb, 
    '{0}', 
    field::jsonb #- '{0,lastName}',
    false)
```

The result from my query above:

```
[
    [
       {
           "firstName": "John"
       }
    ]
]
```

The result that I want:

```
[
    {
       "firstName": "John"
    }
]
```

Comment: Simple answer: you can not ! If you want your desired result then you have to copy the thing without the parts you want deleted. You may set them to zero or undefined but  they would still be there.

Comment: At least when you run over them with Object.keys(). The Name will remain.

Comment: Just a thought! How about deleting this record and adding a new one? i.e. No editing stuff

Comment: You want to delete a record from a json object, not an array. Should fix your question's title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the first element of the array (not the whole array) in the third parameter:

```
UPDATE person
SET 
    field = jsonb_set(field::jsonb, 
    '{0}', 
    (field::jsonb->0) - 'lastName',
    false)
```

Answer (score 0):

The unneeded jsonb_set is causing the problem in this case.  Get rid of it.

```
UPDATE person
SET 
    field = field::jsonb #- '{0,lastName}'
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try with REGEXP_REPLACE.

The super basic pattern would be something like `"lastName":"[a-zA-Z]*"`.

For a better one please see [regular expression for first and last name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385701/regular-expression-for-first-and-last-name#2385967).

Answer (score -2):

I can say it is impossible. Please don't try it.

Comment: I did not down vote but comments should stay in comment section since it is not an answer, so wait till you have enough reputation to comment (50).

Comment: In addition to what Ajan wrote: it's not impossible