# How can I change my regex to eliminate consecutive identical special characters?

Tags: regex, validation

My regex works on validating first and last names. The acceptable forms are as follows:

- Jacob Wellman
- Wellman, Jacob
- Wellman, Jacob Wayne
- O’Shaughnessy, Jake L.
- John O’Shaughnessy-Smith
- Kim

The unacceptable forms are as follows:

- Timmy O’’Shaughnessy
- John O’Shaughnessy--Smith
- K3vin Malone
- alert(“Hello”)
- select * from users;

My current regex is as follows.

```
^[\w'\-,.][^0-9_!¡?÷?¿\\+=@#$%ˆ&*(){}|~<>;:[\]]{2,}$
```

It works properly for validating all of the names except for:

- Timmy O’’Shaughnessy
- John O’Shaughnessy--Smith

The reason for this is that the regex doesn't take into account consecutive identical special characters. How can I change my regex to take those into account?

Comment: This could help you:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385701/regular-expression-for-first-and-last-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude consecutive characters by using a negative lookahead with a backreference to assert not a character directly followed by the same character `^(?!.*([’-])\1`

Note that your current pattern matches names that are at least 3 letter long, and will not match for example names like `Al`

If you want to match that as well, you can change `{2,}` to `+` in the pattern.

```
^(?!.*([’-])\1)[\w',.-][^\n\r0-9_!¡?÷¿\\+=@#$%ˆ&*(){}|~<>;:[\]]{2,}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RM32Vg/1)

Matching names can be difficult, this page has an interesting read about names:

[Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. Sidenote, what can I change to limit the number of a special character.

Comment: @AliKhabib Do you mean the number of "special" characters like `’` and `-` in the whole string?

Answer (score 0):

```
^(:?[^0-9'\-\., _!¡?÷?¿\\+=@#$%ˆ&*(){}|~<>;:[\]]+(:?['-]|, | |\.|\. |$))+$
```

I used your forbidden characters set and added `'\-\.,` . Then I let them repeat `+`. I insert a group of allowed divisors: `(:?['-]|, | |\.|\. |$)` and allow repeating this pattern `+`.
I tried it [here](https://regex101.com/r/7EHQI8/1).

Answer (score 0):

You could do it separately, before your validation. With a Perl regex, to remove additional special characters, it would be:

```
s/(\W)\1+/$1/g
```

so for example:

```sh
$ echo "John O’’Shaughnessy--Smith" | perl -C -pe 's/(\W)\1+/$1/g'
John O’Shaughnessy-Smith
```