# Allow spaces in this regex

Tags: php, regex

I've used this regex before in my username match, but now I want to be able to allow spaces. How do I go about doing this?

```
            if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $teamname)) {
                $errors[] = "Team name can only contain letters, numbers, and no spaces.";
            }
```

Comment: Do you mean spaces before and after a username? or allow spaces within the username? e.g. is `"my awesome username"` valid? Or do you mean `"   myawesomeusername  "` (note the spaces either side).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex for names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275160/regex-for-names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/', $teamname)) {
    $errors[] = "Team name can only contain letters, numbers, and spaces.";
}
```

Just add a space in.

Comment: Worked brilliantly. Thank you!