# strip_tags enough to remove HTML from string?

Tags: php, html, string, strip-tags

The site user can sign-up on a site, and during sign-up he can provide a name.

I want this name to be a valid name, and free of any HTML and other funky characters. Is strip_tags enough for this?

Comment: What about *whitelisting* rather than blacklisting? If you require usernames to conform to certain requirements like "no funky characters", only allow a certain range of characters and check for that instead of the other way around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find that there's no single function for idiot-proofing user inputs. Best to mix a few together:

```
$val = trim($val);
$val = strip_tags($val);
$val = htmlentities($val, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); // convert funky chars to html entities
$pat = array("\r\n", "\n\r", "\n", "\r"); // remove returns
$val = str_replace($pat, '', $val);
$pat = array('/^\s+/', '/\s{2,}/', '/\s+\$/'); // remove multiple whitespaces
$rep = array('', ' ', '');
$val = preg_replace($pat, $rep, $val);
$val = trim($val);
$val = mysql_real_escape_string($val); // excellent final step for MySQL entry
```

Comment: obviously, put this in a function ... `function sanitize($val) { ... }` ... then call sanitize on anything you want scrubbed

Comment: Don't forget to put argument in quotes in your INSERT query, otherwise all of this escaping is for nothing!

Comment: "excellent final step for MySQL entry" should be "critical final step". It's actually the only step you you *must* do.

Comment: "Best to mix a few together" - Don't willy nilly mix random functions together. Apply each function for a specific purpose, not because more is better.

Answer (score 2):

Regex could fit well with less code:

`^[A-Z]'?[- a-zA-Z]( [a-zA-Z])*$`

Here we have good examples:

[Regex for names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275160/regex-for-names)

Comment: [Nǃxau ǂToma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C7%83xau) has a bone to pick with your regex.