# How to remove HTML from a value when sending $_POST / $result with jQuery PHP?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a jQuery script which onClick Button requests and imports values from a PHP file and inserts this values to a form.

Now I can successfully get values to the correct fields but the problem is the values **contains HTML codes** and I do need **only TEXT** results.

I need value for Field: "**Ethnicity**" and Value should be: "**Caucasian**"

I have tried different ways to see the values of `$ethnicity` and the wired thing is:

```
echo $ethnicity;                   // result: Caucasian
var_dump($ethnicity);              // result: string(146) " Caucasian "
$result['ethnicity'] = $ethnicity; // result: {"ethnicity":" Caucasian<\/td>\r"}
```

As you can see the $result value is: `"Caucasian<\/td>\r"`

I tried also:

```
$result['ethnicity'] = ($ethnicity->textContent);   // result: It says "null"
```

**My question is**: How can I remove this HTML codes from this value?

Comment: try `strip_tags($ethnicity)`

Comment: @rynhe: Now using strip_tags it removed "**<\/td>**" but "**\r**" is still there. Now it looks like: `" Caucasian\r"`. Can I remove the whitespace/space before word Caucasian also?

Comment: @Cyborg, Check the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is strip_tags for that
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

```
$result['ethnicity'] = strip_tags($ethnicity);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `strip_tags`

```
$ethinicity=strip_tags($ethinicity);
```

(or)

Make use of this function [From PHP Source Manual]

```
<?php 
function html2txt($document){ 
$search = array('@<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>@si',  // Strip out javascript 
               '@<[\/\!]*?[^<>]*?>@si',            // Strip out HTML tags 
               '@<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>@siU',    // Strip style tags properly 
               '@<![\s\S]*?--[ \t\n\r]*>@'         // Strip multi-line comments including CDATA 
); 
$text = preg_replace($search, '', $document); 
return $text; 
} 

$ethinicty=html2txt($ethinicity);
?>
```

**EDIT:**

> Now using strip_tags it removed "</td>" but "\r" is still there. Now
>   it looks like: " Caucasian\r". Can I remove the whitespace/space
>   before word Caucasian also?

```
  $ethnicity = str_replace(' \r','',strip_tags($ethnicity));
```

Answer (score 0):

By using [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) and [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)  function

```
$str = filter_var(trim($ethinicity,'\t\n\r\0\x0B'), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$val = trim($val);
$val = strip_tags($val);
$val = htmlentities($val, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); // convert funky chars to html entities
$pat = array("\r\n", "\n\r", "\n", "\r"); // remove returns
$val = str_replace($pat, '', $val);
$pat = array('/^\s+/', '/\s{2,}/', '/\s+\$/'); // remove multiple whitespaces
$rep = array('', ' ', '');
$val = preg_replace($pat, $rep, $val);
$val = trim($val);
$val = mysql_real_escape_string($val); // excellent final step for MySQL entry
```

There is no single function to separate string........

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371486/strip-tags-enough-to-remove-html-from-string#9371514)