# PHP string validation - Firstname_Lastname

Tags: php

I'd like to get some help regarding PHP.
Let's say I have a string ($fullname).
I want to validate that it's in the form of "Firstname_Lastname".
For example, make sure that it's "Nathan_Phillips" and not "Nathan Phillips" or "Nathan122" etc.
Can you guys help me with the function?

Thanks in advance! :-)

------------ EDIT -------------
Thank you guys! Managed to do that. Also added the numbers filter. Here's the function:

```
function isValidName($name)
{
    if (strcspn($name, '0123456789') != strlen($name))
        return FALSE;
    $name = str_replace(" ", "", $name);
    $result = explode("_", $name);
    if(count($result) == 2)
        return TRUE;
    else
        return FALSE;
}
```

Usage example:

```
if(isValidName("Test_Test") == TRUE)
    echo "Valid name.";
else
    echo "Invalid name.";
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Please share your attempts so far as @GordonM said. Some thoughts are to check for spaces, split on the underscore, etc. Show us what you're trying.

Comment: I tried to split the input strings to two string by using the "split" function, splitted by the "_" (underscrore) character, though it didn't prevent users from putting several cells like "Nathan_Joshua_Phillips", or "Nathan_12345".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try something like this:

```
function checkInput($input) {
    $pattern = '/^[A-Za-z]{2,50}_[A-Za-z]{2,50}/';
    return preg_match($pattern, substr($input,3), $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
}
```

This will accept a string containing 2-50 alphabetic characters, followed by an underscore, followed by 2-50 alphabetic characters.

I'm not the best with regex, so I invite corrections if anyone sees a flaw.

If you have special characters (*è*, *í*, etc.), the regex I gave probably won't accept it. Also, it won't accept names like *O'Reilly* or hyphenated names. See this:

[Regex for names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275160/regex-for-names)

I'll let you track down all the exceptions to the regex for names, but I definitely think regex is the way to go.

Comment: Amazing. I will use this one!

Comment: One more thing - what about invalid characters? Like ', ", / etc.

Comment: You can alter the regex to accept those if you want. It's up to you what you want to accept.

Comment: I tried to do the following:
'/^[A-Za-z][^']{2,50}_[A-Za-z][^']{2,50}/'
To disallow the ' character, but seems like I'm a newbie.

Comment: What I have will disallow the `'`. Do you mean you want to allow it?

Comment: Sorry, was my bad.
Thank you very much, woz!