# validation for form php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forms, validation

I have a form that user can submit their information and comment to the website. However, I am having the problem in validating my forms.For example, I can submit an empty form and add in numbers in my name. By right it should be wrong and echo out the message. However, I can still submit it and my validation code is not working for the form. 
My code is below:

```
    <?php
error_reporting(~E_NOTICE); // avoid notice

require_once 'dbconfig.php';


if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
    $firstname  = $_POST['firstname'];//firstname
    $lastname = md5($_POST['lastname']);//password
    $phone = $_POST['phone']; // user name
    $enquiry  = $_POST['comment']; // user job


// Initialize error array.
    $errors = array();
    // Check for a proper First name
    if (!empty($_POST['firstname'])) {
        $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
        $pattern = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9\_]{2,20}/"; // This is a regular expression that checks if the name is valid characters
        if (preg_match($pattern, $firstname)) {
            $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
        } else {
            $errors[] = 'Your Name can only contain _, 1-9, A-Z or a-z 2-20 long.';
        }
    } else {
        $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your First Name.';
    }

    // Check for a proper Last name
    if (!empty($_POST['lastname'])) {
        $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
        $pattern = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9\_]{2,20}/"; // This is a regular expression that checks if the name is valid characters
        if (preg_match($pattern, $lastname)) {
            $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
        } else {
            $errors[] = 'Your Name can only contain _, 1-9, A-Z or a-z 2-20 long.';
        }
    } else {
        $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your Last Name.';
    }

    //Check for a valid phone number
    if (!empty($_POST['phone'])) {
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $pattern = "/^[0-9\_]{7,20}/";
        if (preg_match($pattern, $phone)) {
            $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        } else {
            $errors[] = 'Your Phone number can only be numbers.';
        }
    } else {
        $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your Phone number.';
    }
    if (!empty($_POST["comment"])) {
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    } else {
        $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your enquiry infomation.';
    }
    // if no error occured, continue ....
    if (!isset($errMSG)) {
        $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('INSERT INTO user_message(firstname,lastname,phone,enquiry) VALUES(:fstname, :lastname, :phone, :enq)');
        $stmt->bindParam(':fstname', $firstname);
        $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
        $stmt->bindParam(':phone', $phone);
        $stmt->bindParam(':enq', $enquiry);


        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $successMSG = "enquiry succesfully submitted ...";
            header("refresh:5;contactus.php"); // redirects image view page after 5 seconds.
        } else {
            $errMSG = "error while inserting....";
        }
    }
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Boostrap 3 example</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
              <link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

        <link href="css/maincss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <?php
            if (isset($errMSG)) {
                ?>
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> <strong><?php echo $errMSG; ?></strong>
                </div>
                <?php
            } else if (isset($successMSG)) {
                ?>
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                    <strong><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> <?php echo $successMSG; ?></strong>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
            ?>  
            <h2>Contact us</h2>
            <br/>
            <p>Fill out the form below.</p>
            <p>* required field.</p>
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
                    <tr> 
                        <td><label >First Name*:</label></td>
                        <td><input name="firstname" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr> 
                        <td><label >Last Name: </label></td>
                        <td><input name="lastname" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr> 
                        <td><label >Phone Number: </label></td>
                        <td><input name="phone" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr> 
                        <td><label >Enquiry: </label></td>
                        <td><textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <input name="" type="reset" value="Reset Form" /> 
                            <button type="submit" name="submitted" class="btn btn-default">Create</button><br/>

                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap3/js/bootstrap.js"></script>       
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my database design: 
[image]

Comment: You can add the `required` attribute to your `input`-tags if you are using HTML5.

Comment: For the name You should use regular expression like this `/^[A-z]+$/` because You need only alphabet

Comment: @stackoverflowuser - Some people have double names using spaces or hyphens. And a lot of people have characters that are not a-z. You can't be very strict, when it comes to names, or you risk alienating a lot of users. But the current validation is wrong, though. It does allow for numeric names and `_`, which I've never seen anyone having in their name?

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson Yes, my fault, I just write this validation very quickly without much thinking. However some validations of this topic should do the job. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275160/regex-for-names) or, as You mention before, check only length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue 1

You populate an array called `$errors` with the error-messages, but you then check `$errMSG`. That variable will never be set. Change to:

```
if (!$errors) {
    // your database code
```

That should stop it from inserting anything, if any errors occurse.

#### Issue 2

Your regex allows for any alpha character and/or numeric values and/or underscores as long as it is between 2 and 20 characters long, which means that: `aaaaaaaaaaaa`, `1111111`, `_______` all are considered valid names.

Validating names are tricky, since there are people with characters outside of a-z (foreign names) and double names with spaces, dashes, apostrophes etc. I recommend to simply check the length of the name, like:

```
if (strlen(trim($firstname)) >= 2 || strlen(trim($firstname)) <= 20) {
    // .... ok
} else {
    // .... error
}
```

***Note:** I wouldn't have 20 as the maximum length. Your DB-columns are 100 in length so..  allow for that, at least. Don't assume that everyone has usual names.*

#### Issue 3

In the beginning, you populate `$enquiry = $_POST['comment']`. Later, you do: `$comment = $_POST['comment']` and then use `$enquiry` in the database insert.

There are likely more things you could fix, but these are the once that stands out and are the root of the issues in your question.

Comment: Thx!! The code is working now but I am not so sure how to apply the Issue 2 solution to my code. May u extend a little bit on this ?

Comment: Simply replace your `if (preg_match(....))`. It this answer solved your issue, feel free to mark it as answered.