# Python: Error:TypeError: findall() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to scrub a text document with specific parameters. Have tried different iterations of the `x=...` line but the program isn't able to read the all line.

```
import re
#import csv

text = open(r'C:\Users\Vincent\Documents\python\theSortingHat\100000DirtyNames.txt') #open text file
for line in text: #iterate through every line
    #return list of names in that line
    x = re.findall ('^([a-zA-Z]-?$')
    #if an actual name is found
    if x != 0:
        print(x)
```

I receive:

> Error:TypeError: findall() missing 1 required positional argument:
>   'string'

Comment: You are not using the `line`variable which contains the text you want to search for a regular expression. Please refer to the documentation of `re` or `re.findall` before posting a question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to **find** something in a **string**. The problem is that you gave `re.findall` only the one parameter, you should also give `line` as a parameter.
You also had some problem with your regex and you didn't close your group (i.e. `()`), what made it to a not valid regex.

This is the answer that you are aiming for:

```
import re

text = open(r'C:\Users\Vincent\Documents\python\theSortingHat\100000DirtyNames.txt') #open text file
for line in text: #iterate through every line
    #return list of names in that line
    x = re.findall('^([a-zA-Z])-?$', line)
    #if an actual name is found
    if x != 0:
        print(x)
```

---

About the regex, sounds like this [post might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275160/regex-for-names)
TL;DR:
you can use this regex maybe:

```
^[A-Z]'?[- a-zA-Z]+$
```

Comment: thanks!   is there a reason why it returns only []?   I have 10000 names in the text file.   many have letters.  However, I want to exclude the ones that have special characters (other than -)

Comment: It happen because your regex didn't "caught" anything. you need to fix your regex...I;m not sure what you try to achieve, but I edited my answer to give you some links

Comment: I appreciate your help.  :)    I am trying to filter out all the non-names in the document.  I have not completed the code but want to eventually send all non-names to one csv file and all the actual names to another csv file.I managed to have it read the entire line but it doesn't filter out the non-names.   New code:  lines = open(r"C:\Users\Vincent\Documents\python\theSortingHat\100000DirtyNames.txt").readlines() #open text file
for line in lines: #iterate through every line
    #return list of names in that line
    if re.search(r"[a-zA-Z]+", line):
        print(line, end="")

Comment: I figured, this why I gave you that regex and a link to the post I took it from. There is a thing of accepting answer in SO, it is being used by clicking on the green arrow  next to the relevant answer

Comment: Probably worthwhile to note that `x != 0` will always be true, since `re.findall` returns a list of strings, never a number. Maybe just `if x`? That will at least fail if `x == []`.